# MAX32660 MCU not outputting correct processor times

Tags: c, time, embedded, printf, clock

I recently purchased a dev board for the max32660 MCU. I followed the instructions from the company's YouTube videos on how to set it up and got the example files working using the Eclipse IDE. I intend to use the time.h library to keep track of how long it takes to run various parts of my code, but whenever I try to printf() any clock_t type variables I just get back repeated 0.000000 values.

For the record: I am simply using my Arduino serial monitor to watch the signals come in from my USB port.

Maxim integrated youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpYBBYLkjTY&t=339s

Max32660 webpage
https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/microcontrollers/MAX32660.html

Code:

```
/***** Includes *****/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "mxc_device.h"
#include "led.h"
#include "board.h"
#include "mxc_delay.h"
#include "time.h"

/***** Definitions *****/

/***** Globals *****/

clock_t start;
clock_t end;

/***** Functions *****/

// *****************************************************************************
int main(void)
{

    printf("Hello World!\n");

    while (1) {
        start = clock();
        MXC_Delay(500000); //This part works fine
        end = clock();
        printf("%Lf\n", start); //I've tried many different versions of this
    }

}
```

I've tried many different printf() configurations (%f, %lf, %ld, %s, %d, %i) and I cannot tell if the variables "start" and "end" are actually being saved as that value or if there is some problem with my serial port monitor reading the printf() statement, even though the "Hello World!" statement prints just fine.

I would expect to see any number besides 0.000000 being returned, particularly some integer that represents the number of clock cycles. I also expect that number to be somewhat low since the call to clock() is early in the script.

Comment: 1. by default printf does not support floats. 2. very unlikely that clock() will work. It is not big hosted system :)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to print `end - start`?

Answer (score 0):

In most embedded standard libraries `time()` and `clock()` are not implemented or implemented as a "weak-link" stubs.  You normally have to implement them yourself.  In this case `clock()` and `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` are implementation dependent, you need to "re-targetting" the library to map this function to the hardware resources *you choose* to assign to that function.  On a Cortex-M4 that would normally be a counter incremented in the SYSTICK interrupt at whatever rate (`CLOCKS_PER_SEC`) you choose for your platform.

You may already have support for SYSTICK and a system clock; in which case your `clock()` implementation might simply be a facade for that existing functionality.

Even if you had a working `clock()` the code:

```
printf("%Lf\n", start);
```

Is unlikely to produce a useful result in any case:

- `start` is of type `clock_t` which is likely an alias for `long`, but certainly not `long double`.
- Since any `clock()` implementation will be synchronous with whatever clock is used for `MXC_Delay()` the test simply measures itself!
- `end` is unused so you are simply showin elapsed time, not the iteratuion time (that may be intended, in which case `end` is redundant).  Perhaps you intended:

```
printf("%ld\n", (long)(end - start) ) ;
```

or possibly:

```
printf("%f\n", (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC ) ;
```

- I would doubt that on this target that `long double` is any larger than `double` in any event.